# Process connection_type after resolved

Tags: graphql, graphql-ruby

I use graphql gem 1.8.11.

My `UserType` has `notifications` connection field and if it is queried I'd like to perform some operation (`read!` in example below).

Example below performs the operation for all of association field.
Even if `notifications` field has pagination parameter and not all of `notifications` are queried, the operation is performed for all `notifications`.

How can I perform the operation only for queried nodes?

```
module Types
  class UserType < Types::BaseObject
    implements GraphQL::Relay::Node.interface

    field :id, ID, null: false
    field :notifications, NotificationType.connection_type, null: true

    global_id_field :id


    def notifications
      object.notifications.tap { |o| o.read! }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up to customize connection class.

app/graphql/types/notification_type.rb:

```
module Types
  class NotificationType < Types::BaseObject
    #
    # existing code
    #

    class << self
      def connection_type_class
        @connection_type_class ||= Types::NotificationConnectionType
      end
    end
  end
end
```

app/graphql/types/notificaiton_connection_type.rb:

```
module Types
  class NotificationConnectionType < GraphQL::Types::Relay::BaseConnection
    def nodes
      super.map(&:read!)
    end
  end
end
```